# Can I create a Body object without copying memory?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm trying to implement a `PUT` request that transmits some bits to a web service:

```
extern crate reqwest;

fn put(buf: &[u8]) {
    let v = Vec::from(buf);
    let body = ::reqwest::Body::from(v);
    // execute the request
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the memory copy (which, if I understand correctly, occurs when constructing the vector) when constructing the `Body`?

I'm potentially sending large buffers and I'd prefer to avoid unnecessary copies (even if they're negligible compared to the network IO)

Comment: You probably meant `Body::from(v)`, since `Body` implements `From<Vec<u8>>`. The brief answer to the question is "you can't, `Body` needs to own the content`".

Comment: It may still be worth mentioning how you obtained the `&[u8]` in the first place. Can't the original source be moved to the request body?

Comment: @E_net4 This is actually an `impl Write` that writes the buffer to an external web service